# Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin: building ios failed

Tags: ios, facebook, ionic-framework

When i try to run ionic build ios
or try to build archive for the xcode project created by ionic i get this error

> **FacebookConnectPlugin.m**:27:44: error: no visible @interface for 'CDVPlugin' declares the selector 'initWithWebView:' self =
>   (FacebookConnectPlugin *)[super initWithWebView:theWebView]; ~~~~~
>   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hybrid-mobile-app/platforms/ios/qudratApp/Plugins/phonegap-facebook-plugin/FacebookConnectPlugin.m:238:28:
>   warning: comparison of constant 2 with boolean expression is always
>   false [-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare] if
>   (!command.arguments == 2) { ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~ 1 warning and 1
>   error generated.
>
> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed: CompileC
>   build/qudratApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulatorqudratApp.build/Objects-normal/i386/FacebookConnectPlugin.o
>   qudratApp/Plugins/phonegap-facebook-plugin/FacebookConnectPlugin.m
>   normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (1
>   failure) Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args:
>   -xcconfig,/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hybrid-mobile-app/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,qudratApp.xcodeproj,ARCHS=i386,-target,qudratApp,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,build,VALID_ARCHS=i386,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hybrid-mobile-app/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hybrid-mobile-app/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

Comment: You having much luck with this issue? i'm on my second day and still no luck. Our errors do look slightly different, but much the same with @interface for 'CDVPlugin'.

Comment: Nopes no luck still, i have removed facebook from ios for now untill i get a fix for it,
What exactly is your error

Comment: Issue has been resolve, refer to: https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/issues/1227

Answer (score 7):

I installed the phonegap plugin facebook through a locally cloned copy and also re-add the FacebookSDK.framework to Xcode after installation, but none of this worked to me. The way I solved was installing https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4.

1. Remove the phonegap plugin:

   `ionic plugin rm phonegap-facebook-plugin`
2. Clone the next plugin:

   `git clone https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4.git`
3. Add the plugin manually:

   `cordova -d plugin add PATH/cordova-plugin-facebook4 --variable APP_ID="*****"  --variable APP_NAME="*****"`

Thats how it works to me.

Comment: That worked for me as well and saved a lot of time :)

Comment: FYI you can have the plugin add do all the download work for you. eg `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --variable APP_ID="*****"  --variable APP_NAME="*****"`

Answer (score 1):

You can Solve this in 2 ways:

1- replace `[super initWithWebView:theWebView]` by `[super init]`.

2- add a compiler flag to FacebookConnectPlugin.m to disable ARC, the compiler flag is -fno-objc-arc

From my point of view, I recommend the second solution because it's not affecting the code.

if you are looking for a step by step solution do the following in Xcode.

1. Select your main project.
2. Select your target
3. Go to build phases
4. Expand the compiled resources tap select "FacebookConnectPlugin.m"
5. At the right side of the "FacebookConnectPlugin.m", you can add the
   following compiler flag

   -fno-objc-arc

Now if you want to understand the problem in details:

The FacebookConnectPlugin.m was built under non-ARC environment and he controls his memory consumption. but Xcode doesn't allow that as it's using ARC to control the memory consumption of the whole app. so the solution for this conflict is to revamp the FacebookConnectPlugin.m Code to use ARC or simply tell the Xcode that you are responsible for the memory management of this class by adding the compiler flag.

Answer (score 0):

As of today the plugin https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4 still works on `Android`, but not on `iOS` anymore. The fork https://github.com/cordova-plugin-facebook-connect/cordova-plugin-facebook-connect with exactly the same API/CLI command works on `iOS` and I fixed the problem using https://github.com/cordova-plugin-facebook-connect/cordova-plugin-facebook-connect.